# python date on file want to strip off microseconds

Tags: datetime, python-3.x

I'm really getting nowhere with Python date processing. A csv file I am accessing has the datetime in this format ( each row is a separate data point)

```
2016-01-11 01:00:01.504424
2016-01-11 01:00:01.427073
```

and I want to strip off the 01:00:01.504424 (time) leaving just the date portion so I can detect when the day changes. There has to be an easy way to do this but I can't seem to get it. I even tried loading it all into a tuple before I realized I must have lost the plot..

```
tryagain = datetime.strptime(prev_day, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f")
t = tryagain.timetuple()
for i in t:
    print(i)
```

I can't believe stripping off the microseconds is hard it's just I can't seem to get it to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f` format is correct for the provided datetime strings. Get the `date()` component, and, if needed format into string again:

```
>>> prev_day = "2016-01-11 01:00:01.504424"
>>> prev_day_date = datetime.strptime(prev_day, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f")
>>> prev_day_date.date()
datetime.date(2016, 1, 11)
>>> prev_day_date.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
'2016-01-11'
```

Or, you can just split it by space and get the first part:

```
>>> prev_day.split()[0]
2016-01-11
>>> datetime.strptime(prev_day.split()[0], "%Y-%m-%d")
datetime.datetime(2016, 1, 11, 0, 0)
```

Comment: thank you so much Alecxe, for some reason I thought it would be cleaner than this BUT I see what is going on and I would have not got there without your help. Thanks again and have an excellent week.

Comment: @theakson: what is a cleaner way to get only the date portion compared to the `.date()` call?

Comment: JfSebastian I am new to Python so the two calls strptime then strftime were not obvious to me. @alecxe set me on the right path. I am not aware of any "cleaner" way to do this as my thoughts were tending towards a call that read the "2016-01-11 01:00:01.504424" into a tuple but alecxe's approach is bettter.